# Algoritmo de recombinação

Tags: algoritmo, complexidade-de-algoritmo

Imaginem o seguinte cenário: um posto de gasolina é autuado por sonegação fiscal por emitir nota fiscal de cupons fiscais já emitidos - o que ocorre é que cada veículo das empresas conveniadas ao posto abasteciam e ao final do mês o posto emitia uma nota fiscal junto com a respectiva fatura.

A operação, no entanto, foi feita errada por quase 2 anos. Não houve sonegação em nenhuma hipótese, todavia, não foram referenciados os números de cupons fiscais às notas fiscais.

Estamos falando de uma massa de dados imensa, onde precisamos basicamente de um match para quantidade de litros por tipo de combustível x valor - por exemplo: uma nota fiscal de R$ 32.127,12 e 19.047,61 Litros de óleo diesel tem que ser "reagrupada" com N cupons fiscais.

Todavia, temos os seguintes problemas: o preço dos combustíveis variam, pois a nota fiscal pode ser a combinação de N bombas x N impressoras fiscais, ou seja, estamos falando de uma massa de dados estratosférica.

Todavia, sabendo que podemos limitar o raio de "busca" de recombinação por data (últimos 30 dias) - (o que em volume de dados de resume a trilhões de combinações neste período), poderíamos utilizar algum algoritmo de árvore? Ou algum algoritmo variante do caixeiro viajante?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que você está lidando com um [problema da mochila](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problema_da_mochila), em inglês [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). É um problema NP-completo, então não tem nem solução rápida, e o desempenho só piora com o aumento de itens. Mencionou que é uma massa enorme, então sem muita esperança.

A vantagem, no seu caso, é que os cupons fiscais tem data, e possivelmente hora. *Supondo que a conta fecha*, o que você pode fazer é ordenar esses cupons por data e hora, e de trás para frente vai somando todos os itens até igualar ou superar a nota de data mais próxima. Igualou, deu sorte: retira os cupons utilizados, marca a nota como ok, e recomeça. Falhou a soma você "desiste" do último cupom ainda vivo, e repete o processo. Essa solução supõe que o sistema que emite ordens faz um processo semelhante, pegando so cupons em aberto e fechando em pacotes.

Mas a hipótese que a conta fecha é na verdade muito frágil. Uma alternativa daí é fechar somas de notas por dia, por os dias que "tem certeza" em certas notas, e daí ficar pinçando os cupons "incertos" na nota do mês anterior ou posterior, conforme tiver espaço nessa ou naquela.

Solução mesmo, só vocês conseguindo do(s) posto(s) que aprontaram essa a relação de cupons e notas. Qualquer outra coisa, mesmo a solução knapsack perfeita de todos os cupons em todas as notas **não garante** que essa foi a relação original. É só uma aproximação como qualquer outra nesse problema indeterminístico.

Comment: Consegui resolver parte do problema com uma implementação do algoritmo! Obrigado